# Orbifold vs Alexandrove space vs Limit of manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I have a question about some defitions : 
  Orbifold, Alexandrov space, limit of manifolds in Gromov-Hausdorff distance sense.

Consider following example.

Let $r> 0$

$L_c = \{ (x cos \theta, x sin \theta, cx) |  0 \leq x$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi \}$

$S$ : $(z-\sqrt{2} r)^2 + x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

$T$ : $ (z- \sqrt{2} R)^2 + x^2 + y^2 = R^2$

If $R$ is sufficiently large, then we have a two dimensional sphere $U_c$ enclosed by
   $L_c$, $S$, and $T$.

First notice the following. $lim_{r \rightarrow 0} U_c$ is an 
   orbifold for some $c$

Question : Is any orbifold is a limit of manifolds in Gromov-Hausdorff sense ?

If this question is wide, we can restrict to the case of nonnegatively curved orbifolds.
   : Is a nonnegatively curved $n$-orbifold a limit of positively curved $n$-manifolds ?

Question 2: In the following paper, a space with curvature $ \geq k$ is defined.

M. Gromov Y. Burago and G. Perelman, A.d. alexandrov spaces with curvature bounded
   below, Uspekhi Mat. Nauk 47 (2) (1992), 3–51.

Is a $n$-dimensional space with curvature $ \geq k$, which is smooth except 
  finite points, is a limit of $n$-manifolds of 
  positive sectional curvature $\geq k$ ? I believe that this question is trivial and 
  it is true.

I do not think that all orbifolds or spaces with curvature $ \geq k $ are limits of 
  manifolds.

However I can not deny it.

Since ${\bf R}^3={\bf R}^4 /S^1 = lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} {\bf R}^4/{\bf Z}_k$, 
  orbifolds are different from spaces with curvature $ \geq k $. But they are 
  obtained from the sequences of manifolds.

MOTIVATION : Hsiang-Kleiner classified positively curved manifolds with $S^1$-action. 
  I want to extend this result to positively curved orbifolds with $S^1$-action.

If orbifold is a limit of manifolds then the problem is simple.

Accordingly I want to know the questions. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Every compact length space is a Gromov-Hausdorff limit of two-dimensional Riemannian manifolds. You need to be more precise in your question. Do the approximating manifolds have to have the same lower curvature bound? Same dimension?


Comment: @ IVanov : Thank you. Your suggestion is helpful for me. 

Comment: One technical point: Orbifolds are different animals than topological spaces. An orbifold is a space plus some extra structure. That said, I think that your question is fairly self explanatory (at least in this regard). 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Q1.** Note that one oriented orthonormal frame bundle $FO$ over a smooth orbifold $O$ is a smooth manifold.
This frame bundle admits a one-parameter family of metrics which collapse to the original manifold and its curvature can be made bounded from below.

*Proof.* Equip $FO$ with $SO(n)$-invariant metric, consider product space $[\varepsilon\cdot SO(n)]\times FO$ and factorize along diagonal action. (This often called Cheeger's trick, but I think it was known before Cheeger.)

**Q2.** It is an open question. It is expected that cones over some positively curved manifolds can not be approximated. Vitali Kapovitch has examples of such $n$ dimesional cones which can not be approximated by $m$-dimensional manifolds with $m< n+8$.

Answer (score 9):

By Perelman's Stability Theorem, if a (compact) limit of $n$-dimensional Alexandrov spaces of curvature $\ge k$ has the same dimension, then the convergent spaces are eventually homeomorphic to the limit space. So in this context a limit of manifolds is always a topological manifold.

And there exist non-manifold examples of Alexandrov spaces, e.g., $\mathbb R^3/\{id,-id\}$ which is the cone over $\mathbb {RP}^2$. Or, if you want a compact example, take $S^3/\mathbb Z_2$ where $\mathbb Z_2$ acts on $S^3$ with two fixed points (think of $S^3$ lying in $\mathbb R^4$ and consider the reflection in some 1-dimensional axis). This is a compact orbifold of curvature $\ge 1$ and it is not a limit of manifolds of the same dimension with a uniform lower curvature bound.